# Show Date Tag in Recyclercview chat and filter data w.r.t date like in whatsapp

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a recycler view with multiview types (For Incoming and Outgoing) messages and a static list which I am passing to the adapter to test my UI. My goal is to sort view holders' messages w.r.t data like we have in whatsapp. I have a separate viewholder for date as well.

Custom Object

```
class ChatTempModel(val viewType: Int, val senderName : String, val date: Long, val message : String, val clinicalList: ArrayList<ClinicalTeam>? )
```

This is my Chat Adapter Code:

```
class ChatAdapter(private val context: Context, private var list: ArrayList<ChatTempModel>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

private lateinit var clinicalTeamAdapter: ClinicalTeamAdapter

companion object {
    const val VIEW_TYPE_FIRST = 12
    const val VIEW_TYPE_DEFAULT_CHAT = 0 //Default Static Text
    const val VIEW_TYPE_INCOMING_CHAT = 1 //Incoming
    const val VIEW_TYPE_OUTGOING_CHAT = 2 //Outgoing
    const val VIEW_TYPE_PDF_UPLOAD = 3 //OutgoingPDF
    const val VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE_UPLOAD = 4 //Outgoing Image
    const val VIEW_TYPE_DATE = 5
    const val VIEW_TYPE_PDF_INCOMING  = 6
    const val VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE_INCOMING = 7
}


private inner class FirstChatViewHolder(private val binding: ItemFirstMessageBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(position: Int) {
        val recyclerViewModel = list[position]
        binding.apply {
            tvSenderName.text = recyclerViewModel.senderName
            tvInComingMessage.text = recyclerViewModel.message

          //  tvTime.text = recyclerViewModel.date.toString()
            tvTime.text = getDateTime(recyclerViewModel.date)
        }

    }
}


private inner class DefaultChatViewHolder(private val binding: ItemDefaultChatViewBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(position: Int) {
        val recyclerViewModel = list[position]
        binding.apply {
            tvInComingMessage.text = recyclerViewModel.message
            //tvTime.text = recyclerViewModel.date.toString()
            tvTime.text = getDateTime(recyclerViewModel.date)
            tvSenderName.text = recyclerViewModel.senderName
            clinicalTeamAdapter = ClinicalTeamAdapter(context)
            clinicalTeamAdapter.submitList(recyclerViewModel.clinicalList)
            rvClinicalTeam.adapter = clinicalTeamAdapter

        }

    }
}


private inner class IncomingChatViewHolder(private val binding: ItemIncomingChatBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(position: Int) {
        val recyclerViewModel = list[position]
        binding.apply {
            tvInComingMessage.text = recyclerViewModel.message
            //tvTime.text = recyclerViewModel.date.toString()
            tvTime.text = getDateTime(recyclerViewModel.date)
            tvSenderName.text = recyclerViewModel.senderName
        }

    }
}


private inner class OutgoingChatViewHolder(private val binding: ItemOutgoingChatBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(position: Int) {
        val recyclerViewModel = list[position]
        binding.apply {
            tvInComingMessage.text = recyclerViewModel.message
           // tvTime.text = recyclerViewModel.date.toString()
            tvTime.text = getDateTime(recyclerViewModel.date)
            tvSenderName.text = recyclerViewModel.senderName
        }


    }
}

private inner class PDFChatViewHolder(private val binding: ItemPdfUploadViewBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(position: Int) {
        val recyclerViewModel = list[position]
        binding.apply {
            // tvInComingMessage.text = recyclerViewModel.message
          //  tvTime.text = recyclerViewModel.date.toString()
            tvTime.text = getDateTime(recyclerViewModel.date)
            tvSenderName.text = recyclerViewModel.senderName
            tvPdfName.text = "Jack's Blood Test.pdf"
        }


    }
}


private inner class ImageUploadViewHolder(private val binding: ItemImageUploadViewBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(position: Int) {
        val recyclerViewModel = list[position]
        binding.apply {
            //tvTime.text = recyclerViewModel.date.toString()
            tvTime.text = getDateTime(recyclerViewModel.date)
            tvSenderName.text = recyclerViewModel.senderName
                context.loadImage(recyclerViewModel.message, binding.ivUploadedImage)
            ivUploadedImage.setOnClickListener{
                val b = Bundle()
                b.putString("abc",recyclerViewModel.message)
                val navController = context.let { Navigation.findNavController(it as Activity, R.id.nav_host_fragment_dashboard) }
                navController.navigate(R.id.fullScreenImageFragment,b)
            }
        }


    }
}



private inner class PDFIncomingViewHolder(private val binding: ItemPdfIncomingViewBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(position: Int) {
        val recyclerViewModel = list[position]
        binding.apply {
            // tvInComingMessage.text = recyclerViewModel.message
          //  tvTime.text = recyclerViewModel.date.toString()
            tvTime.text = getDateTime(recyclerViewModel.date)
            tvSenderName.text = recyclerViewModel.senderName
            tvPdfName.text = recyclerViewModel.message
        }


    }
}

private inner class ImageIncomingViewHolder(private val binding: ItemImageIncomingViewBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(position: Int) {
        val recyclerViewModel = list[position]
        binding.apply {
          //  tvTime.text = recyclerViewModel.date.toString()
            tvTime.text = getDateTime(recyclerViewModel.date)
            tvSenderName.text = recyclerViewModel.senderName
                context.loadImage(recyclerViewModel.message, binding.ivUploadedImage)
            ivUploadedImage.setOnClickListener{
                val b = Bundle()
                b.putString("abc",recyclerViewModel.message)
                val navController = context.let { Navigation.findNavController(it as Activity, R.id.nav_host_fragment_dashboard) }
                navController.navigate(R.id.fullScreenImageFragment,b)
            }
        }


    }
}


private inner class DateViewHolder(private val binding: ItemDateViewBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bind(position: Int) {
        val recyclerViewModel = list[position]
        binding.apply {
         //   tvDate.text = getDateTime(recyclerViewModel.date)
         //   tvDate.text = "30 Sep, 2021"
            tvDate.text = getDate(recyclerViewModel.date)
        }
    }
}


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_DEFAULT_CHAT) {
        return DefaultChatViewHolder(
            ItemDefaultChatViewBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(
                    parent.context
                ), parent, false
            )
        )
    } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_INCOMING_CHAT) {
        return IncomingChatViewHolder(
            ItemIncomingChatBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )

    } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_OUTGOING_CHAT) {
        return OutgoingChatViewHolder(
            ItemOutgoingChatBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_PDF_UPLOAD) {
        return PDFChatViewHolder(
            ItemPdfUploadViewBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE_UPLOAD) {
        return ImageUploadViewHolder(
            ItemImageUploadViewBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(
                    parent.context
                ), parent, false
            )
        )
    } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_DATE) {
        return DateViewHolder(
            ItemDateViewBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    } else if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_PDF_INCOMING){
        return PDFIncomingViewHolder(ItemPdfIncomingViewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent,false))
    } else if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE_INCOMING){
        return ImageIncomingViewHolder(ItemImageIncomingViewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false))
    }
    else {
        return FirstChatViewHolder(
            ItemFirstMessageBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if (list[position].viewType == VIEW_TYPE_DEFAULT_CHAT) {
        (holder as DefaultChatViewHolder).bind(position)
    } else if (list[position].viewType === VIEW_TYPE_INCOMING_CHAT) {
        (holder as IncomingChatViewHolder).bind(position)
    } else if (list[position].viewType == VIEW_TYPE_OUTGOING_CHAT) {
        (holder as OutgoingChatViewHolder).bind(position)
    } else if (list[position].viewType == VIEW_TYPE_PDF_UPLOAD) {
        (holder as PDFChatViewHolder).bind(position)
    } else if (list[position].viewType == VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE_UPLOAD) {
        (holder as ImageUploadViewHolder).bind(position)
    } else if (list[position].viewType == VIEW_TYPE_DATE) {
        (holder as DateViewHolder).bind(position)
    } else if(list[position].viewType == VIEW_TYPE_PDF_INCOMING){
        (holder as PDFIncomingViewHolder).bind(position)
    } else if(list[position].viewType == VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE_INCOMING){
        (holder as ImageIncomingViewHolder).bind(position)
    }


    else {
        (holder as FirstChatViewHolder).bind(position)
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return list.size
}
```

}

[image: Goal is to show date view holder and sort message like whatsapp.]

Goal is to show date view holder and sort message like WhatsApp.